# Is nonduality sufficiently different from Buddhism to warrant its own site on SE?

Tags: discussion

In theory, nonduality is not very different from Buddhism. In practice, I think it is.

There is a large and growing, widely dispersed "movement" of people studying Advaita, Emptiness and other forms and paths of nonduality. The language is sufficiently different that it is not Buddhism. I think a new site is in order. Thoughts please?

Answer (score 2):

There are many schools of Buddhism that don't subscribe to non-duality. Advaita vedanta is its own system that is probably better classified as Hinduism than Buddhism, I think.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose you are right. Buddhism is about (as I understand it) the path to the end of suffering, and nonduality is about the end of whatever-the-heck thing thinks that it exists to suffer at all. I don't want to take refuge under Hinduism, I want to support the many people learning about nonduality with no real background or view at all. Maybe I need to ask the question somewhere else. It certainly didn't kick up much activity.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to understand how the new sites are created in the StackExchange network: all new proposals go through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).You can create a proposal that goes through different stages. Later in the beta stage sufficient activity is needed for the site to be accepted:

> 10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work.
>
> 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work.

You wrote in your comment: *"I want to support the many people learning about nonduality with no real background or view at all."*

The StackExchage network is designed on the principle of specific questions & answers and people usually need to have *a little* background information to be able to ask the questions.

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I did look at Area51 and start a proposal. I don't know many people though and am not on social media, so I hope I can reach those who might be interested. I did think about what sort of questions might be asked and the background of participants. I looked at Hinduism SE which has an Advaita tag, but it is so full of questions about ancient stories, characters and myths that it didn't seem like it would fit for most people I know of who have had some kind of awakening. These experiences are varied and have little to do with religion or study. Its a shot in the dark!